# Unsigned Bytes CRC32 in Java

Tags: java, hash, checksum, crc32

I'm trying to replicate the CRC32 hashing function that is available in PHP in Java.  The existing CRC32 class within Java returns a different hash and I believe it is because the Java bytes in my byte array are unsigned -128 through 128 instead of 0-255.

What I'm failing to figured out is how to work around this situation.  I've looked at using Guava's UnsignedBytes, but I can't find a hashing method that takes it as an argument.  I could use that to write my own hashing function, but frankly I don't nearly enough about how it works or bitwise arithmetic in general to make that plausible.

In the simplest terms I'm trying to CRC32 has a string and return the decimal representation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CRC does not care about sign.

Java's CRC32 gave me same result than PHP's.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Hello World!";
    CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    crc.update(a.getBytes());
    System.out.println(Long.toHexString(crc.getValue()));
}
```

Outputs: `1c291ca3`

Using [this online PHP CRC32 calculator](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/crc32/) gave the same CRC value than above Java code.

Comment: Thanks.  Stupid mistake.  The value I was looking at in my test data set was the last value and I wasn't calling crc.reset() at the end of my loop and I didn't fully understand what update() did.